Make HTML Element Invisible When It Is Under Another Element
Say I have two divs, one large and one small. When the small div overlaps the large div I want the small div to be hidden, but only the part under the div. So if half of the small div is under the large div I only want half to be hidden. Example:
<div id="largeDiv" style="position:absolute; width: 20%; height: 20%;"></div>
<div id="smallDiv" style="position:absolute; width: 5%; height: 5%;"></div>

I have tried using z-index and display properties in css, but to no avail.

Only the largeDiv needs a positive z-index. On top of that, you need to add a non-transparent background (other then default) on the largeDiv:


// for demo purpsoe only
marginOffsetSlider.addEventListener('input', function() {
  smallDiv.style.top = `${this.value}vh`;
})
.container {
  position: relative;
}

#largeDiv,
#smallDiv {
  position: absolute;
}

#largeDiv {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#smallDiv {
  top: 30vh;
}


/* for demo purpose only */
.container {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#largeDiv,
#smallDiv {
  min-height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

#largeDiv {
  background-color: blue;
}

#smallDiv {
  background-color: green;
}
<label for="marginOffsetSlider">Margin-Top offset: </label><input type="range" id="marginOffsetSlider" min="0" max="60" value="30">

<div class="container">
  <div id="largeDiv">Large Div</div>
  <div id="smallDiv">Small Div</div>
</div>




The example above does not seam to be working in my project. Here is my code if you want to see
The project is a redesign concept for the Windows OOBE.
